# Materialized view: compilation_error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, materialized-view

When executing the following code on the SCOTT schema I receive a compilation_error.
What am I doing wrong here? I doesn't even tell me what the error is.

```
SQL> create materialized view dept_emp_mv as (  
  2      select dname, job, hiredate, count(*) nbr  
  3                  from emp e  
  4                  join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno  
  5                  group by dname,hiredate,job);  
Materialized view created.  
SQL>  
SQL> select staleness from user_mviews where lower(mview_name) = 'dept_emp_mv';  
STALENESS  
-------------------  
FRESH  
SQL>  
SQL> insert into emp values (8003, 'TEST', 'TEST', 7902, to_date('20131127','YYYYMMDD'), 2500, null, 20);  
1 row created.  
SQL>  
SQL> commit;  
Commit complete.  
SQL>  
SQL> select staleness from user_mviews where lower(mview_name) = 'dept_emp_mv';  
STALENESS  
-------------------  
NEEDS_COMPILE  
SQL>  
SQL> execute DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('DEPT_EMP_MV','C', parallelism => 1);  
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.  
SQL>  
SQL> select staleness from user_mviews where lower(mview_name) = 'dept_emp_mv';  
STALENESS  
-------------------  
COMPILATION_ERROR
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

With Oracle 12c this issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: Explain plan the query in the materialised view to make sure it's parsing correctly. Have you any triggers on the table that could be causing dependant object invalidation?

Comment: Actually, try refreshing it again. I bet it changes back and is ok.

Comment: Refreshing it again still causes the compilation error. There are no triggers on the table, this table comes from the demo schema 'SCOTT'

Comment: Executing the query outside of the materialized view works perfectly and displays a correct result. The explain plan contains a hash, merge join and sort operation with a total cost of 7. This is a pretty basic query in my opinion.

Comment: After refreshing it again is the data actually correct? I remember seeing that status in the past, and in one situation it was ignorable

Comment: The data inside the materialized view is indeed correct but why is the staleness set to 'COMPILATION_ERROR' ? I actually query for this value inside my program to see if the materialized view can be used.

Comment: There is a list of possible reasons in support.oracle.com (Doc ID 1414046.1). Have you checked it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Oracle doesn't like ANSI-style joins in the materialized view definition when refereshing...

Changing the definition to

```
create materialized view dept_emp_mv as  
   select dname, job, hiredate, count(*) as nbr  
               from emp e, dept d
               where e.deptno = d.deptno
               group by dname,hiredate,job;
```

makes it work for me.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f706b/1

Changing the definition in the SQL Fiddle back to the one included in the question will cause the `staleness` to be `COMPILATION_ERROR`.

Personally, I would classify this as a work-around rather than an answer.

Comment: That is indeed a good work-around. I find it very strange though that Oracle cannot handle a JOIN, since it is perfectly correct syntax.

Comment: My sentiments exactly and would like to know *why* the ANSI-join (at least in this case) results in a "compilation error".

Comment: Good spot! Definitely a bug Oracle need to fix.